# Setting the word space with ragged2e

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I am working on Lyx with Preamble, I used to set the word space with `everysel` as below:

```
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{%
\fontdimen2\font=0.3em% interword space
}
```

However, the design I am working on has to perform well in a very small format, hence I opt to use `ragged2e` to set ragging right with hyphenation:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight
```

With a sense of despondency, this seems to disable the `everysel`, the [manual](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ms/ragged2e.pdf) said when `ragged2e` is called upon, the `everysel` is automatically loaded, however, I don't seem to be able to get it working.

So to sum up, my question is, how to set the text ragging right, with hyphenation and maintaining the control of word space?

Comment: Move the call of `\EverySectFont` after `\usepackage{ragged2e}`. Otherwise add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: stupid me! it is working now. sorry about this.

Comment: As the author of `ragged2e` I'm curious if you think code for this should be added to the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see, `\RaggedRight` performs `\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont` *before* your `\EverySelectfont` can act; this macro sets the space skip to `\fontdimen2\font`, so your setting is ignored, because TeX uses `\spaceskip` if non zero, rather than `\fontdimen2\font` for the interword spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everysel,ragged2e,etoolbox}

% Let's add something before \spaceskip is set
\makeatletter
\preto{\@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont}{\fontdimen2\font=.3em }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\RaggedRight abc def

\Large abc def 

\end{document}
```

Another way is to set `\EverySelectfont` *before* loading `ragged2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{\fontdimen2\font=.3em }

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\selectfont

\RaggedRight abc def

\Large abc def

\end{document}
```

Don't forget `\selectfont` after `\begin{document}`.